# Issue with redirecting to subdomain .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having an issue with .htaccess. I got 2 websites one is in main root folder other is in root/subdomain.

I got .htaccess for handling subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Problem which I met is that url looks like:
https://sub.domain.com/sub.domain.com/

I want to hide the sub.domain.com via .htaccess.

Also I want to mention that everything works correctly on http.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add following code in your sub-domain .htaccess file and check it again

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. ;<